# Help with Trailhead - Lightning Component Basics - Attributes & Expressions

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, trailhead

Has anyone had any success completing the [Lightning Component Basics - Attributes & Expression](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/lex_dev/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/units/lex_dev_lc_basics_attributes_expressions)s module?   I attempted the challenge using the Trailhead playground. And think what I did is correct. Yet I get the following error...

*"Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The Packed field is either not using the lightning input component, the checked value of the item's Packed__c attribute or the correct type of input"*

Following is the component I have written:

Component Bundle Name : "campingListItem"

```
<aura:component >  
  <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="True"/>
  <ui:outputText value="{!v.item.Name}"/>
  <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" style="currency"/>
  <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}" style="decimal"/>
  <lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Packed?" name="packed" checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}"/>      
</aura:component>
```

Object schema is :   Name - Text (80),  Packed__c - Checkbox,  Price__c - Currency (16,2), Quantity__c - Number (18,0).

What could I be doing wrong. Any advice?

Comment: There are 3 possibilities mentioned in the error message. Carefully check all 3. I can see one that isn't correct based on what the challenge asks for. A big hint is that SLDS has multiple ways to present boolean values.

Comment: Yes!  Got it!!  :)   Toggle!

Comment: can you please upload the answer. I am getting the problem in toggle too

Comment: Same issue i am facing.